# Transition error when checking-in work item for VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Here's the error I was getting in VS2015: "One or more checked work items failed the transition testing due to invalid field values. Please correct the values and retry the check-in."

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I had this when checking in an associated work item and flagging the item as resolved. So

1. Work item in in progress
2. Check in with this work item marked as resolved
3. Work item is updated to ready to test

BUT

the work item can't move into the new state as it needs additional information. In my case TFS is set to assign the bug back to the person that raised it. It was such an old bug that the person raising it had left the company and doesn't exist in TFS - hence the error.

Moral of the story - fix bugs quicker.

Comment: This ultimately became my fix as well, to simply mark it as "associate" instead of "resolve."  Thanks, also I love crab buckets with lemon and butter.

Comment: I had similar problem. Opened work item via browser and noticed a rule related with original estimate field. If you have a rules on work items, you can check them additionally.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was forced to do the Associate since I got the error message. When I went into the Work Item in VSTS I manually resolved it and it prompted me to set a required field. Were that required field set, the Resolve from Visual Studio would have worked.

Comment: I.e. -- on the Work Item row, select "Associate" in the dropdown. Then Check-in again.

Comment: @DonCheadle thank you, your answer finally explicitly said what needed to be done.

Answer (score 4):

I faced same issue while check in from visual studio.

Change the related work item as associate instead of resolve from visual studio solved my issue.

[image]

Comment: This is eventually what I started doing.  Thanks @Mohanvel V

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround : Create a new task/bug in your VSTS for whichever story.  Then assign your check in to that work-item. That's what the error is somewhat saying... Difficult for me to decipher at first, hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the task status you have created for your TASK. You should set your task state -- Development or other, You get an error because "state" is "new"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using DevOps 2019 on-prem and I had 1 little update to share.

I created the Bug on the Web Portal and kept it open, added the Ticket Number for the checkin and got the above error.

**EASY FIX :**

- Remove Ticket from Checkin
- Close Ticket in Web Portal
- Re add Ticket
- Checkin
- ALL IS GOOD.